# ¿Cómo establecer SRC de input type image con código base 64 con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de mostrar  imágenes  dinámicamente, pero no me está funcionando.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Creo una tabla d la siguiente manera donde una columna posee un botón que al hacer click muestra una modal donde se debería visualizar la  imagen:

```
function CrearTablaConsolidado(emp) {
    $('#tableConsolidado tbody tr').remove();
    $.each(emp, function (index, item) {
        let tr = `<tr> 
                      <td style="text-align: center;"> ${index + 1} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${item.Nombre} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${item.Apellido} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: justify;"> ${item.Dni} </td>
                      <td style="text-align: center;"> <input type="button" value="Historia" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:80px;" onclick="MostrarHistoria('${item.Dni}','${item.Email}','${item.Foto}');"> </td>
                      <td style="text-align: center;"> <input type="button" value="Email" class="btn btn-success" style="width:80px;" onclick="PreventEnviarEmail('${item.Dni}','${item.Email}','${item.Nombre}','${item.Apellido}');"> </td>
                      </tr>`;
        $('#tableConsolidado tbody').append(tr);
    });
}
```

Código donde se establece el SRC de la imagen:

```
function MostrarHistoria(dni, email, foto) {

    var inMagen = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.concat(foto);
    $('#alumno').attr('src', inMagen);
    console.log(inMagen);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Procesor/GetHistoriaAsistenciaPerson",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { dni: dni},
        success: function (data) {
            try { data = JSON.parse(data); } catch{ NavePage('../Home/Autentication'); }
            CrearTablaHistoria(data, inMagen);
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log('MostrarHistoria');
        }
    });
    MostrarModal();
    return false;
}
```

Código HTML:

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content3">
            <div style="float:right;">
                <span id="cerrar" class="close" onclick="CerrarModalUpdate();">&times;</span><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;"> <h4> Historial Asistencia</h4></div><br />
            <div style="float:left;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="tableHistoria" class="display table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="tableH">
                                            <th>Nª</th>
                                            <th>Materia</th>
                                            <th>Inasistencias</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="btn-danger" id="total"> </label>
            </div>

            <div style="float:right">
                <input type="image" id="alumno" name="alumno"  src="" class="imgCarnet"><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Que es exaxtamente lo que no funciona?¿

Comment: muestra la imagen ...el src no se establece